# RD-TZ40 ME Replacement

Tags: shimano, derailleur, replacement

I've damaged the rear derailleur on my bike, and it needs to be replaced. I don't really have an LBS. I've looked around online, but I can't seem to find a correct replacement. I should clarify that both the derailleur and the mounting bracket are damaged.

Where can I find a replacement for my derailleur?

[image: This is a picture of the bracket, removed from the bicycle.]

Comment: Tourney and it's variations/clones are probably the most widespread rear derailleurs. If some place nearby sells new bikes, I'd go and ask there. Or check out local online ad boards.

Comment: It was like the second one I saw when I Googled `RD-TZ 40 ME`.

Comment: @DanielRHicks What do you mean? When I did the same search, the derailleurs seemed to not have the correct brackets.

Comment: The "hanger" is separate from the derailer.  Remove that bolt in the center of your picture and the hanger comes off.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SHIMANO-RD-TZ40-TZ40-SIS-TOURNEY-mountain-bicycle-bike-Riding-Cycling-MTB-18-21speed-Bike-Rear/32816711034.html

Comment: I agree with Daniel - you've merged the frame-specific hanger with the generic derailleur into one object.

Comment: There are several outfits online that specialize in replacing hangers.  There was a question in the past 2-3 days that linked to them.